# Browser not close automatically when I install in-house app iOS via website

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I distribute ios app with in-house license and users will download it via a website when they tap in link same as below

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/app.plist" style="text-decoration: none;" >
```

The pop-up confirm is displayed, and users tapp "Install" button, Actually, the download progress is started on homescreen, but the problem the screen not change anything and they don't know the download progress is started or not

How can the browser close automatically and show download progress after users tap "Intsall" button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know,It can not be done.Even many special app test website just make an toast to tell user "the app is installing,click home button to check"

Comment: I just check this on iphone 5s - iOS 7, the browser close automatically, but on iOS 9, it cannot. I don't know what happen on iOS 8, I don't have device to check.